# How were the rabbis able to talk to brides?

Tags: wedding

We know the famous Gemara about כיצד מרקדין לפני הכלה and the different opinions of what to say to the bride on how she looks. Also there is the famous halacha to drop whatever you’re doing and escort the bride if she passes by you.

My question is, weren’t the rabbis very against excessive (or any really) talk with women? Why would the rabbis be allowed to “dance” with a married bride and compliment her on her looks, is this not inappropriate? What’d exactly was the procedure of this custom and how’d the rabbis do it without crossing any lines or inspiring any lewd thoughts?

Comment: You don't dance "with" the bride; you dance "before" her. And you escort the wedding party, not the bride specifically.

Comment: Definitionally, "excessive" means _more than_. More than the above halachos would be "excessive"?

Comment: @N.T. Although there was Rav Acha who put the bride on his shoulders

Comment: @JoelK And doesn't the gemara ask why it was allowed?

Comment: Saying nice things about the bride doesn't mean saying them to her and dancing before her doesn't mean dancing with her

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Rabbis are not against talking to women. They are against excessive talking to women. What is excessive?

The Mishna in Avot 1:5 says:

> אַל תַּרְבֶּה שִׂיחָה עִם **הָ**אִשָּׁה
>
> Don't speak excessively to **the** woman

There is an interesting הָ/"the" in line. Ostensibly, it comes to mean "wife" rather than any woman, which would seem to go with the rest of the Mishna, but that הָ still isn't necessary for that.

I once heard an interesting *diyuk* on it. The Mishna is teaching us how to be a *mentsch* (this is Avot after-all). How does a *mentsch* talk to a woman?

> A man flies from NYC to Boston for business. On the way out, he sits next to a man. The whole flight, the only thing he says to the man is "excuse me" when he needs to get out to go to the bathroom.
>
> On the way back to NYC, he is sat next to a woman. This flight is very different, because he strikes up a conversation with her from the get go, and keeps it going whenever he can think of something new to say.

What's the difference? Both cases should be the same: he had nothing to say to the man and no reason to strike up any conversation, so he didn't. The same should have been true for the woman, but it's not so. The difference is, she is *the woman*.

The Mishna is explaining that this man isn't viewing her as a *mentsch*, a dignified human being. If he did, he wouldn't say anything to her unless he had a reason to do so, just like he does with men. However, he doesn't view her as a *mentsch*, he views her as "the woman". He's not talking to *her*, he's talking to "the woman". Therefore, he talks "excessively"; he finds extra, unnecessary things to say simply on account of her womanhood, and this is very silly, and not something a *mentsch* should be doing.

So, I think there is a misunderstanding in the premise of the question. Being a woman doesn't default preclude a man from talking to her, although there is definitely reason to not talk to her *just because she is a woman*.

---

May I recommend that you look up if it is *mutar* for a man to compliment a woman's looks, halachically, and if not ask why this is an exception?

Comment: Fair enough, what you say at the end is really the ikar of my question. How can we/the rabbis be allowed to compliment a married bride on her looks? It seems very iffy and unfaithful to your wife maybe, or it seems like it can lead to thoughts about this bride, especially considering you have to look at her to see what she looks like and compliment her

Comment: @CuriousYid I am currently doing some interesting research that might be related to that. I am trying to work out the views on a 4th category of gazing, which is gazing simply to appreciate beauty, without _enjoying_ it.

Comment: Then again we also have that bracha you make when seeing a beautiful person, so it clearly must be mutar. It just seems sketchy you know. Like even thinking about Gemara stories with all these rabbis talking to women and looking at them is perplexing because at least nowadays it’s the norm for a rabbi (or anyone really) to look down when they’re walking and not even gaze at a woman

Comment: @CuriousYid don't leave it in the "sketchy" zone. Keep digging. Torat Hashem Temima

Comment: @CuriousYid You're saying that the Gemara is sketchy because it seems to contradict modern norms.  You should be asking in reverse - modern norms are sketchy because they seem to contradict the Gemara.

Comment: @Heshy I assume the modern norms of looking down around women are based on actual halachic sources…

Comment: @CuriousYid If R' Moshe seems to contradict a Tosfos, you ask on R' Moshe, not on Tosfos.  I'm not saying the norms are wrong (also not saying they're not), I'm saying that asking from them on the Gemara is backwards.

Answer (score 1):

The Prishah (Even Ha'ezer, Siman 65, note 1) adds another possible explanation of the term כלה נאה, that it's meant to reference not the kallah's external beauty, but נאה במעשה, or "beautiful in her deeds."